# Force Pi 3B+ Raspian (not NOOBS) to boot in composite mode automatically (using config.txt?)

Tags: boot, pi-3b+, config.txt, composite

Please do not echo the noise of similar questions and answers. None seem to meet my need.

What is the minimum set of config.txt commands that I need to ensure that my Pi 3B+ outputs to composite when it powers up?

For example...

```
# First Video Display
framebuffer_priority=3

# Normal NTSC
sdtv_mode=0

# Disable or Enable HDMI
hdmi_ignore_hotplug=1  # Disable HDMI (for Composite)

# 4:3 aspect ratio
sdtv_aspect=1
```

Those commands don't seem to work for me. Does the order matter? What will do what I need?

Comment: have  you tried https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41796/composite-video-on-boot

Comment: If there's no HDMI connected then your RPi3B+ automatically boots to SDTV. It defaults to `state 0x40000 [NTSC 4:3], 720x480 @ 60.00Hz, interlaced` so PAL users may need some tweaks in /boot/config.txt.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `hdmi_force_hotplug=` is either 0 or commented out. You shouldn't need anything else, just don't plug in HDMI and it'll boot to composite mode.